# System.diagnostics and System.Debug not working from Page Method

Tags: asp.net, pagemethods, system.diagnostics

We have a Page Method on a web page using ASP .Net. We tried to put in a trace statement using both System.Diagnostics and System.Diagnostics.Debug. In Visual Studio 2008, the break point is not even hit for the line, but other break points on other lines are hit.

There is no output from either method that we can see.

There is also a Global.asax error catcher that works fine in other cases, but in the Page Method is not being catched.

Any ideas why a Page Method and System.Diagnostics do not play well together?

Comment: Is your code compiled as `'Debug'` or `'Release'`?

Comment: We are in Debug mode. Also, Debug versus Release does not affect Diagnostics.Trace

Answer (score 0):

try using System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, "MessageString");